# PHP wizard required, re-order/sort posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, sorting

I have posted this up in various forums, but no luck so far (hope its ok to post it here also?)...I have been trying for a few weeks...no success.

I have two pages on my blog (top rated and most viewed) which return a column of posts (with titles/thumbs), but at the top of these column's I would like to "filter" these posts into week/month/all time. (Since I followed a tutorial, I wanted to keep it the same, so I will change the sorting options from date etc later).

The following code is mean refresh the page and load the new url like example.com/top-rated/?o=title-asc. But so far it displays the popular posts and the drop down menu with options...when I click nothing actually happens.

I have piggybacked my site on a friends domain, if anybody could take a look at let me know what you think...it would appreciated.

Thanks in advance folks :)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Top Rated
*/
get_header();  ?>

<?php
if( isset($_GET['o']) && $_GET['o'] != '')
          {
              $order = $_GET['o'];
              switch($order)
              {
                case 'date-asc': $orderby = 'order=ASC';
                            $msg = 'Date Ascending';
                              break;

                case 'date-desc': $orderby = 'order=DESC';
                            $msg = 'Date Descending(default)';
                              break;

                case 'date-mod': $orderby = 'orderby=modified';
                                $msg = 'Date Modified';
                               break;

                case 'title-asc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=ASC';
                                $msg = 'Title A-Z';
                                break;

                case 'title-desc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=DESC';
                                $msg = 'Title Z-A';
                                break;

                case 'comment': $orderby = 'orderby=comment_count';
                                $msg = 'Comment Count';
                                break;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              $orderby = 'order=DESC';
              $msg = 'Date Descending (default)';
          }
?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="sorter-container">
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var orderby = jQuery('#order-by');
                var str;
                orderby.change(function(){
                    str = jQuery(this).val();
                     window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/top-rated/?o="+str;
                });
            </script>
<h2 id="sort-heading">Posts ordered by:<?php echo $msg; ?></h2>
        <select id="order-by">
            <option value="date-desc" <?php echo (!isset($order) || $order == '' || $order == 'date-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Desc. (default)</option>
            <option value="date-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'date-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Asc</option>
            <option value="date-mod" <?php echo ($order == 'date-mod')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Modified</option>
            <option value="title-desc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Desc.</option>
            <option value="title-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Asc.</option>
            <option value="comment" <?php echo ($order == 'comment')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Comments Count</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<?php query_posts('meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ){ ?>
    <?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
    <div <?php echo post_class(); ?>>
        <h3> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"class="img_hover_trans"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-small'); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> | <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></small></h3>
         <?php the_excerpt('Read more...'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you make your question short and precise ?? Thank you

Comment: Sorry about that Baba, hopefully this will make it a bit clearer. Im using the above code to create dropdown menu which will sort my posts. It does this by ammending the url `window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/top-rated/?o="+str;` When I select something, it doesnt refresh the page. Im not sure where im going wrong (JQ, missing code etc).. Thanks for taking an intrest in my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some code in the wrong place (sorry, Im new to this)...so finally spotted it after Kemal posted up some code to try. So thanks for the help/support, I will update the OP with the new working code, it should work by copying and pasting into your project. If so, pay close attention to this part `window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/top-rated/?o="+str;` replace top-rated with your page-slug. If anybody figures out how to sort by week/month/alltime, please post up here (As it would be helpful)
`

Comment: You don't have to update the question, just mark this answer as accepted. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the heads up Kemal, I did try but it said I couldnt for some reason. When checking again, it said I can accept my own answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If the tutorial you're following uses a `select` dropdown to change the ordering of the posts, it SHOULD also give you the code the code that handles the change in the selected option from the dropdown. At any rate, you'll want an event handler attached to the dropdown that'll be triggered when the dropdown is changed. Since you're jQuery 1.6.2, this should be sufficient:

```
$('#order-by').bind('change', function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://beetniksound.com/feedme/top-rated/?o=' + $(this).val();
});
```

**Note:** You probably wouldn't want that URL hardcoded in the Javascript. I don't know about Wordpress, but if it has a function that returns the url of the current page (which in this case is http://beetniksound.com/feedme/top-rated/), you might want to use that.

Comment: Hi Kemal, first, I really appreciate you taking time to write out your comment. The tutorial didnt mention any other code (here it is, if you want to look: http://blog.rutwick.com/use-jquery-to-reorder-your-wp-posts-on-the-fly). Regarding your code, I must be doing something wrong, would I use it like:  `<script type="text/javascript">
              $('#order-by').bind('change', function(){
                  window.location.href = 'http://beetniksound.com/feedme/top-rated/?o=' + $(this).val();
              });`  PS - I wil look into a function that returns the current page, thanks for the tip

Comment: Kemal, I have been messing about with your code and finally got it working :) Thanks so much for you help, its taken me around 4 weeks to find an answer and its done (almost). What I did this time, was move your code to above the query_posts, I then decided to move the original code there and it now works? The function that returns the current page, would that be /top-rated/?o="+str; (like in the original code?) Cant thank you enough, brilliant!

Comment: @FrankMorrison Ah!I didn't even realize that your original code already has some javascript that does the same thing as what I posted.  The code didn't work because it was executed when the DOM was not ready. The `select` dropdown element was not yet loaded in the DOM, that's why it didn't work. Moving the javascript code *after* the dropdown or put it inside a callback that is ran after the DOM is ready (e.g. DOMContentLoaded) would make it work. At any rate, glad to hear you managed to fix it.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have tried moving the code if it wasnt for your post, so thanks Kemal...I was about to give up on it :)

Comment: Dont suppose your know how I could $orderby week/month/alltime instead of title/comments/date etc?

Comment: @FrankMorrison I suggest you open a new question for that matter.